# Route [admin/edit/] not defined why

Tags: laravel-5.1

@foreach( $showdata as $aData )
     
      
       id** ) }}">Edit
       X
      
     
  @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route), if your route accepts parameters and you are passing them in then they need to be done like so:

`route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);`

So your code should look like this or something similar:

`{{ route('admin/edit/', ['id' => $aData->id]) }}`

Another way you could do it, with the way you have currently defined it is with the [url](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url) method:

`<a href="{{ url('admin/edit') }}/{{ $aData->id }}>Edit</a>`